# carrierwave in an edit form

Tags: carrierwave

I'm using a form partial to both create and edit a model object that contains an uploader ("file"):

```
= simple_form_for(@document) do |f|
= f.error_notification

.form-inputs
  = f.input :event_id
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :file
  = f.hidden_field :file_cache

.form-actions
  = f.button :submit
```

In the edit form rather than getting the filename associated with the already uploaded file I get "No file chosen". is there a way to get the widget to recognize that the uploader is not nil and use the filename from the uploader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant for security reasons manually set the value in a file input field. The file name reflects the file chosen by the browser but the file has already been uploaded at that point thus why @document.file? would show true if you look. The file_cache is only used to store and resend the attributes already sent not to be confused with overriding the input value of a file field. For example if you changed the hidden field to an input field you would see the same "no file" message.

I realize this is not what you want, but maybe a better way to handel this is to relabel the input to say something like "replace file" and then render out the file nave via 
`@document.file if @document.file?` above the field.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I ended-up with... I added a label above the file containing the current file name if it exists. Thanks.